# Convert array output from Tiny_TDS to Dashing.io Graph format

Tags: ruby, dashing

I'm pretty new at Ruby and Dashing, but I've been able to muddle through so far up until this point.

I am trying to get data from a MS SQL server using Tiny_TDS and into a format that Dashing can handle for it's Graph widget.

I have been working on a basic ruby script to get the output correct before attempting to input into Dashing.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'tiny_tds'

data = Array.new

client = TinyTds::Client.new(:username => 'MYUN', :password => 'MYPW', :host => '192.168.X.X', :database => 'SQL2012', :port => '1433')

rs = client.execute("SELECT Date, KPI_UserCount AS UserCountCurrent FROM     [SQL2012].[dbo].[DashTbl]")

results = rs.each(:symbolize_keys => true, :as => :array, :cache_rows => true, :empty_sets => true) do |rowset| end

for j in (0...rs.affected_rows)
  for i in (0...rs.fields.length)
    #data.push('"x" => ' + results[j].at(i).to_s, '"y" => ' + results[j].at(i).to_s)
  end
end

printf("%5s",results)

 #data = [ { "x" => 1980, "y" => 1323 }, { "x" => 1981, "y" => 53234 }, { "x" => 1982, "y" => 2344 } ]
 # this is what the output is supposed to look like

client.close
```

Currently my output looks like this:

```
[[2015-08-22 20:00:00 -0600, 4913], [2015-08-23 20:00:00 -0600, 4915], [2015-08-24 20:00:00 -0600, 4918]]'
```

I have been experimenting with adding the required formatting into the data array with the for loops, to no avail.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

UPDATE 1: Thanks to the help of engineersmnky, the hash seems to be created correctly.

My updated portion of the script is this:

```
for j in (0...rs.affected_rows)
  for i in (0...rs.fields.length)
  end
  data << {"x" => results[j].at(0).to_s, "y" => results[j].at(1).to_i}
end
```

Now the issue is that Dashing just seems to show the last number of the y axis as the displayed number and doesn't seem to show any graphed points.

UPDATE 2:

This has been resolved. I ended up needing to recreate the array each time the job was run so that the historical data was pulled from SQL.

```
rs = client.execute("SELECT Date, KPI_UserCount AS UserCountCurrent FROM [TSQL2012].[dbo].[DashTbl]")
results = rs.each(:symbolize_keys => true, :as => :array, :cache_rows => true, :empty_sets => true) do |rowset| end
data_count = Array.new 
for j in (0...rs.affected_rows)
  for i in (0...rs.fields.length)
  end
data_count << {"x" => results[j].at(0).to_time.to_i, "y" => results[j].at(1).to_i}
end
send_event('usergraph',points: data_count)
```

The Dashing code looked like this:

```
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1">
  <div data-id="usergraph" data-view="Rickshawgraph" data-title="User Count Today" style="background-color:#336699" data-renderer="area" data-min="3000" data-max="6500"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: You are building a Hash incorrectly try `data << {"x" => results[j].at(i).to_s, "y" => results[j].at(i).to_i}` that should at least get you closer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've changed the way the hash is built and my output now looks like this:  
     [{"x"=>"2015-08-22 20:00:00 -0600", "y"=>"4913"}, {"x"=>"2015-08-23 20:00:00 -0600", "y"=>"4915"}, {"x"=>"2015-08-24 20:00:00 -0600", "y"=>"4918"}, {"x"=>"2015-08-25 20:00:00 -0600", "y"=>"4906"}, {"x"=>"2015-08-26 20:00:00 -0600", "y"=>"4904"}, {"x"=>"2015-08-27 20:00:00 -0600", "y"=>"4915"}] 
When this is sent to the Dashing Graph Widget, it doesn't seem to plot anything.

Comment: That is because you are passing strings and the graph wants numbers if you look at my example I changed `y` from `to_s` to `to_i`. Not sure what format you need for the date object. you could use something like `results[j].at(i).day` to see if it at least works.

Comment: I have corrected it to 'to_i ' for the Y axis, but I need the X to be a full date for when the data spans more than a month. Is there an option to convert the current date to unix timestamp?

Comment: Sure you can use `results[j].at(i).to_time.to_i`. Also seems like the [Rickshaw documentation](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/tutorial/introduction.html) might be worth a read as it appears this is what dashing's graph widget uses.

Comment: Thanks, this is the page I've been working from that referenced the unix timestamps https://gist.github.com/jwalton/6614023

Comment: I can see the reference to `Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time xAxisOptions` in that file. Did it work for you?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for your help. Final code included in the original post.

Comment: glad it worked. you know that the ` for i..` loop is no longer needed in the example also generally `rs.affected_rows.each` is considered more idiomatic ruby.